# How to Keep Dot-Files up to date?

Tags: linux, git, zsh, administration, dotfiles

I've got two computers, one at work and one at home.  The work one has a VM running Arch, and the home one runs Arch natively.  The work one usually stays at work, but push a lot of stuff back and forth with git, so when I work on something at one place, I can pick up where I left off in another.

One thing I do quite a lot is tweak config files, for things like Vim, ZSH, i3, blah blah blah, and I'm getting real sick and tired of having to remember what I did the night before to keep the next machine I'm using up to speed!

I know this is a job for Git, but how should I manage this?  For instance, I have a bunch of dot files all over my home directory in different sub-directories.  I would need to not only keep track of the changes, but also manage the location of those files relative to where they are in any repository that I could create.

The other thing is, some of these dot-files would require software to be installed....So, take i3 for example:  I installed i3 on my home machine and got it to my liking with it's config file...But, simply pulling the dot-files when I get to work won't make much sense, because the work laptop wouldn't have i3 installed on it!  I would have to remember to install such-and-such as well.  Another good example of this is python modules...Sometimes, I'll get something done and forget the exact names of the modules I had to install as python dependencies to get it running.  In this case, simply pulling the config files is only half the story...I would need a script or something to make sure that the backend for these config files is up to date and in place.

I know this is a less than specific question that people like to see on here, but I also feel as though this issue has a tribal-knowledge amount of documentation available for how top quality Unix/Linux users handle this seemingly realistic administration task.  Everyone suggests something very different, and most issues seem related to recovering from a full system failure as opposed to simply staying up to date between two frequently used machines.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) following this [guide](http://brandon.invergo.net/news/2012-05-26-using-gnu-stow-to-manage-your-dotfiles.html).

With this approach all the dotfiles will be in one folder, which can be version-controlled/synced. It creates symlinks, so that the dotfiles can easily updated.

As for installing the software which is needed, the simplest way would be to just create a bash script or file with notes what to do alongside the config:

```
/home/user/
    dotfiles/
        bash/
            .bashrc
            .bash_profile
            .bash_logout
        i3/
            .config/
                i3/
                    [...some files]
        i3.install.sh

$ cd ~/dotfiles
$ stow bash
$ ./i3.install.sh
$ stow i3
```

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of the guide directly into your answer. This is so that the answer may still be of help should the original reference no longer be accessible. Point in case: At the moment of writing this I am unable to reach the guide due to a *403 Forbidden* error. (Which in this case seems to be done to prevent direct links from external pages. The guide can be reached by copy pasting the URL instead of clicking or by navigating to it from the main page).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by placing (most of) my dot files in `~/dotfiles`, which is a [git repo that I regularly push to github](https://github.com/fleutot/dotfiles).

In this repo I also have a script that sets links up at the right location:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(find -name ".*" -type f); do
    if [[ -e $HOME/$f ]]; then
        mv $HOME/$f $HOME/$f.old
    fi
    ln $f $HOME/$f
done
```

So far, the "right location" is only `$HOME`, but it's up to you to make the script create links to other places.

I used hardlinks because git saves symlinks as links by default, but I'm sure there is a way to fix it for symlinks.

In a new version, I extended the script to remove interfering config files such as `~/.config/git/gitk`. I could just as well have set links there instead of in `$HOME`.

It sounds like what `stow` does, it just seemed easy enough to skip involving yet another tool.

---

I am considering putting my `.emacs.d` and `.xmonad` repos as sub-modules in my `dotfiles` repo... Maybe not worth the hassle though, and I'm not unlikely to forget the `--recursive` while cloning.